# Meteor 1.3 angular meteor project with npm and bower

Tags: meteor, bower

tl;dr: how looks the workflow of using npm and bower inside meteor 1.3?

In my project ( meteor + angularjs 1) i use bower for several packages, like ngDraggable. Now i want to upgrade my project to meteor 1.3 and use npm + native bower from npm in my project. As the angular-meteor depends on babel package, the babel package tries to compile all files in bower_components. So i thought, that i might be on false path. Is there any defined workflow using bower within meteor 1.3?

Answer (score 0):

The workflow is using npm and ignoring bower